# SNAP Installation C++

Tags: c++, make, c, makefile, cmake

I am new to Linux and working in its environment. 
I have trouble understanding and installing SNAP library for C++ on Ubuntu 14.04.

I am following [this](http://snap.stanford.edu/snap/install.html) tutorial.

Inside the SNAP directory I run the `make all` command and it compiles the examples and headers, and of course after the test example is running smoothly.

```
cd examples/graphgen
./graphgen -g:w -n:1000 -k:4 -p:0.1 -o:smallworld.txt
```

Also I compile the tests in test with `make run-all-tests` and they all passed.

But I am having this problem.

I don't install the lib and headers somewhere (ex. `/usr/include` or `/lib` or `/usr/lib`…). This example only compile in its directory.

And when I am trying to run my example I get errors like

```
#include <Snap.h> :: error no such file or directory
```

Like I said, I am new to `cmake` and `make`, so I would gladly appreciate your help.

Comment: I guess you're somehow trying to run the source code instead of the executable. Which command are you running?

Comment: Please post your example that I can test it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the path to the header (`snap-core`, `snap-adv`, `glib-core`, `snap-exp`) and the object file `Snap.o`

---

**Example for:** `examples/graphgen/graphgen.cpp`:

```
g++ graphgen.cpp  ../../snap-core/Snap.o -I../../snap-core -I../../snap-adv -I../../glib-core -I../../snap-exp
```

Comment: @Schrodinger You're welcome

Comment: But can you help e with the export PATH var ? 
Also can you make a short tutorial where to copy the files for example in /usr/local/include  and how to export the PATH var in .bashrc ?

Comment: ohh memories...